# Qt installation error after trying all suggested

Tags: qt

I think I tried everything on my Win7 64 machine but still got this error.

[image]

1. Run installer (Qt_SDK_Win_offline_v1_2_en.exe) as administrator in compatibility mode on XP SP2.
2. Include the directory containing nmake and cl into system path
3. reinstall it about 10 times without success.

I verified that the installer worked fine with a Win32 machine.

What else can I try to make this installed without an error?

UPDATE: I just gave up the SDK and downloaded library only. It worked without any problem.

Comment: weird, the pathnames contain mixed slashes, backslashes, and double slashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be how you defined the environment variable.

If you notice the path in the error message, it contains double slashes before the *bin* directory: `harmattan_10.2011.34-1\\bin` and this is a problem on Windows.

You also can't have both `\` and `/` defining a path. Use `\` only.

Comment: Thanks for finding cause of the problem. But I don't get how I can fix the the problem yet. How/where to fix the double slashes?

Comment: How did you defined the path in the environment variable?

Comment: That's why I am asking. I didn't define anything. I just started installer to start the installation. As I said, it is working fine in win32 machine with almost the same settings.

Comment: Ok, what does this mean exactly: `Include the directory containing nmake and cl into system path` ?

Comment: I see what you mean but I added this string `;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin` to the system path.

Comment: I don't have access to a Win 7 64bits box right now, but I'll try later. Meanwhile, why are you running it in compatibility mode?

Comment: Thanks. That's because one of answers suggested it.